# How come there were so many soldiers among asuras?

Tags: puranas

Like devatas were sons of aditi and asuras sons of diti, then from where thousands of them came from? Like they are mentioned having huge number in their armies.

Comment: Pls add more details over context of your question. Where did you read thousands were there? Which war are you referring to?